# Set/Change Default value for all tables (same column name/type)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, default-value

I have numerous databases, across different servers, all containing several dozen tables with a single column in common.
NB - all databases run on SQL Server 2008 R2.

I need to check (and where necessary change) the value in every table named 'tblFAC%'.
The column is named 'SOURCE' and the value should be '((0))'

These are system generated columns, which is why they are both required and (usually) uniform.

What I have found is that very occasionally, I will see the odd wrong entry - normally either {blank} or '(0)' - and the only way to correct this is to open each table in each database, using DESIGN view and then select the 'SOURCE' field and check the default value, amending as necessary.

Therefore, I would like to know whether there is any kind of script that checks the default value of the 'SOURCE' field for all tables named 'tblFAC%' in a database and set them to '((0))' wherever this is not already the case.

Thanks for reading.
Craig

Answer (score 0):

This will show you all schema/tables where the default constraint for `SOURCE` is not set to `((0))`:

```
SELECT  s.name AS schema_
      , t.name AS table_
      , OBJECT_DEFINITION(default_object_id) AS default_value
FROM    sys.columns c
JOIN    sys.tables t
   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
JOIN    sys.schemas s
   ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
JOIN    sys.default_constraints d
   ON c.default_object_id = d.object_id
WHERE t.name LIKE 'tblFAC%'
   AND c.name = 'SOURCE'
   AND OBJECT_DEFINITION(default_object_id) <> '((0))'
```

You could use the above to build an alter statement, I think you'd have to set it up to run on each server, not sure if you can query cross-server sys tables.

**Update, bonus question:**
No time to test this, but to find where no constraint is set you should just be able to change it to a `LEFT JOIN` and check for `NULL`:

```
SELECT  s.name AS schema_
      , t.name AS table_
      , OBJECT_DEFINITION(default_object_id) AS default_value
FROM    sys.columns c
JOIN    sys.tables t
   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
JOIN    sys.schemas s
   ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
LEFT JOIN    sys.default_constraints d
   ON c.default_object_id = d.object_id
WHERE t.name LIKE 'tblFAC%'
   AND c.name = 'SOURCE'
   AND OBJECT_DEFINITION(default_object_id) IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks friend.  That helped a lot.  I have found wrong entries (e.g. single  brackets).  The only problem is that is ignores blank entries.  Can you offer any advice on finding those as well.

Comment: @PieEyed what do you mean by "blank entries"? Do you mean `NULL` values, or do you mean empty strings `''` or something else?